# Retrieving beans that are Scoped prototype with Autowire

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In my XML configuration I have this:

```
<bean id="soap" class="org.grocery.item.Soap" scope="prototype">
        <property name="price" value="20.00" />
</bean>
```

And in my service class I have the "soap" autowired like this:

```
@Autowired
private Soap soap;
//Accessor methods
```

And I created a test class like this:

```
Item soap = service.getItem(ITEM.SOAP);
Item soap2 = service.getItem(ITEM.SOAP);

if(soap2 == soap ){
    System.out.println("SAME REFERENCE");
}
```

And this is my getItem method in my service class:

```
public Item item(Item enumSelector) {
        switch (enumSelector) {
            case SOAP:
                return this.getSoap();
        }
        return null;
    }

@Autowired
private Soap soap;
//Accessor methods
```

Now what I am expecting is that the when I call the this.getSoap(); it will return a new Soap object. However, it did not, even though the soap is declared scoped as prototype. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

When you create the service object, spring will inject an instance of soap object to your service object.So all the calls to `getSoap()` of service will be retrieving the same soap object which was injected when service was created.

Comment: is there a way I can tell it that every time I call the getSoap will return a new soap object?

Answer (score 2):

Renjith explained the why in his answer. As for the how, I know of 2 ways to achieve this:

1. lookup method:

Don't declare the soap dependency as a field, but rather as an abstract getter method:

```
protected abstract Soap getSoap();
```

Whenever you need the soap in your service (like in the getItem method), call the getter.

In the xml config, instruct Spring to implement that method for you:

```
<bean id="service" class="foo.YourService">
  <lookup-method name="getSoap" bean="soapBeanId"/>
</bean>
```

The Spring supplied implementation would fetch a fresh instance of Soap whenever called.

1. Scoped proxies

This instructs Spring to inject a proxy instead of the real Soap instance. The injected proxy methods would lookup the correct soap instance (a fresh one since it's a prototype bean) and delegate to them:

```
<bean id="soap" class="foo.Soap">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Comment: +1 for the lookup method approach, but I don't think the scoped proxy approach will work here.  `service.getItem(ITEM.SOAP)` would return a reference to the proxy, which means that every single method call made on the returned `Item` would generate a new instance of the underlying bean.  I don't think this is what the OP was after.

Comment: I am still a little confused about the look-up method, will I declare it in the xml? if so how?